# BxSlider not working over https in IE ( mixed content warning )

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, https, bxslider

I’m using the BxSlider plugin ( http://bxslider.com/ ) and it’s working fine in all browsers except in IE7/8, where I get the mixed content popup warning.

All my content is being served over https so it must be something in BxSlider. Has anyone had any issues or managed to implement BxSlider over https?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was beating my head all day long so in case you still need a fix, here it goes.This happens because there is a SVG data request in the bxSlider javascript file and IE7 treats this request as unsecured. To fix, in your bxSlider.min.js file replace "data" with "//".
In my case this was causing the mixed content warning:

```
var l="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
```

I replaced "data" with "//" and it fixed the problem.

```
var l="//:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
```